# Does a basic login form need to state required fields to pass accessibility?

Tags: forms, accessibility, login, required-fields, wcag

One of the accessibility criteria is "[3.3.2 Labels or Instructions](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/labels-or-instructions.html)" and one of the ways to meet that criterion is by identifying required fields.
https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H90

Is a website *really* non-conforming though if on a simple username/password login form you do not state that all fields are required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be ok if the username/password fields don't require any special instructions.  If the username was something unusual, like a phone number or membership number, then you'd probably want instructions associated with the input field (via `aria-describedby`).  But for standard username/password fields, you're ok.

The intent of 3.2.2 is "so that users know what input data is expected".  For username/password, it's well known what is expected.  If you had more input fields than just those two, then you **should** mark the fields as required.